# Php over MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I'm a beginner in MongoDB handling with php.

I'm using Windows 8 (64bit), PHP 5.4.3, PHP Extension Build API20100525,TS,VC9 and mongodb-win32-x86_64-2.2.2.

I tried to install the mongodb driver from 
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads

Downloaded the first package and there were 10 driver files inside the package.
I tried with each of those last four drivers which capable of php 5.4
Then found the php.ini file and included the given corresponding line with the driver name.
(ex: extension=php_mongo-1.3.2RC1-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll)

But none of them responded me.
I tried the following sample code to evaluate them.

```
<?php

// connect
$m = new MongoClient();

// select a database
$db = $m->test;

// select a collection (analogous to a relational database's table)
$collection = $db->shafny;

// add a record
$document = array( "name" => "Anderson", "age" => 22 );
$collection->insert($document);


// find everything in the collection
$cursor = $collection->find();

// iterate through the results
foreach ($cursor as $document) {
echo $document["name"] . "\n";
}

?>
```

The I got an error message,

**Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in C:\Wamp\www\Mongo\test.php on line 5**

I hope this unknown class error is raising due to the lack of proper installation of driver. So please anyone guide me to over come this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using WAMP, you should edit the PHP.ini file in  C:\wamp\bin\apache's bin folder or where ever your WAMP Apache PHP.ini file is. Or if you use the Apache installed separately edit its PHP.ini. I think you have edited the PHP.ini in the PHP folder.